# Android SQLite DB table, no such table error only on some devices

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I have searched through the archives to try and find a solution to my issue but all seem to be unrelated. I have had some upgrades to my database since my initial app launch including the addition of 2 new tables. After my most recent release I have received multiple bug reports stating that "no such table" exists, when I know that it does. I have been unable to recreate the reported error on any of my personal devices, and I am not sure what I could change. 
Here is a copy of the error that I am receiving and of the DB Helper class that creates and upgrades the db tables.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.skylandersdb/com.skylandersdb.CharacterDetailActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tblCollectorGroups (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT collectName FROM tblCollectorGroups
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tblCollectorGroups (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT collectName FROM tblCollectorGroups
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1113)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:690)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1430)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1369)
at com.skylandersdb.CharacterDetailActivity.getListCollectorGroup(CharacterDetailActivity.java:925)
at com.skylandersdb.CharacterDetailActivity.loadCollectorGroup(CharacterDetailActivity.java:908)
at com.skylandersdb.CharacterDetailActivity.onCreate(CharacterDetailActivity.java:400)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
... 11 more`
```

and here is my DBHelper class where I create and upgrade my db

```
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
   import android.provider.BaseColumns;
   import android.util.Log;

    public class DBHelper_Skylanders extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = DBHelper_Skylanders.class.getSimpleName();

public static final String DB_NAME = "skylandersDB";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 6;

public static final String TABLE_skylanders = "tblSkylanders";
public static final String C_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
public static final String C_skyid = "skyid";
public static final String C_depth = "depth";
public static final String C_preName = "preName";
public static final String C_mainName = "mainName";
public static final String C_descName = "descName";
public static final String C_element = "element";
public static final String C_figureType = "figureType";
public static final String C_pic = "pic";
public static final String C_primePower = "primePower";
public static final String C_noOfFigures = "noOfFigures";
public static final String C_game = "game";
public static final String C_attackStat = "attackStat";
public static final String C_attackBase = "attackBase";
public static final String C_agilityStat = "agilityStat";
public static final String C_agilityBase = "agilityBase";
public static final String C_defenseStat = "defenseStat";
public static final String C_defenseBase = "defenseBase";
public static final String C_luckStat = "luckStat";
public static final String C_luckBase = "luckBase";
public static final String C_origin = "origin";
public static final String C_phrase = "phrase";

public static final String TABLE_cGroups = "tblCollectorGroups";
public static final String C_cGroupName = "collectName";
public static final String C_cGroup1 = "collection1";
public static final String C_cGroup2 = "collection2";
public static final String C_cGroup3 = "collection3";

public static final String TABLE_collect = "tblCollection";
public static final String C_skylanderid = "skylanderID";
public static final String C_collectid = "collectid";
public static final String C_collectName = "collectName";
public static final String C_collection = "collection";

public String sql = null;

public final Context myContext;

public DBHelper_Skylanders(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    sql = String.format("create table %s (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s INTEGER,  %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s TEXT, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)", 
            TABLE_skylanders, C_ID, C_skyid, C_depth, C_preName, C_mainName, C_descName, C_element, C_figureType, C_pic, C_primePower, C_noOfFigures, C_game, C_attackStat, C_attackBase, C_agilityStat, C_agilityBase, C_defenseStat, C_defenseBase, C_luckStat, C_luckBase, C_origin, C_phrase, C_collection);
    //test script
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate sql: "+sql);
    //executes SQL statement
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = null;

    sql = String.format("create table %s (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)", 
            TABLE_cGroups, C_ID, C_cGroupName, C_cGroup1, C_cGroup2, C_cGroup3);
    //test script
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate sql: "+sql);
    //executes SQL statement
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = null;

    sql = String.format("create table %s (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)", 
            TABLE_collect, C_ID, C_skylanderid, C_collectid, C_collectName, C_collection);
    //test script
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate sql: "+sql);
    //executes SQL statement
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = null;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    switch(oldVersion)
    {
        case 3:
            db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_skylanders);
            Log.d(TAG, "onUpdate dropped table " + TABLE_skylanders);

            db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_cGroups);
            Log.d(TAG, "onUpdate dropped table " + TABLE_cGroups);

            db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_collect);
            Log.d(TAG, "onUpdate dropped table " + TABLE_collect);

            onCreate(db);

        case 4:
            //only drops tblSkylander
            db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_skylanders);
            Log.d(TAG, "onUpdate dropped table " + TABLE_skylanders);

            //only recreates tblSkylander
            sql = String.format("create table %s (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s INTEGER,  %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s TEXT, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)", 
                    TABLE_skylanders, C_ID, C_skyid, C_depth, C_preName, C_mainName, C_descName, C_element, C_figureType, C_pic, C_primePower, C_noOfFigures, C_game, C_attackStat, C_attackBase, C_agilityStat, C_agilityBase, C_defenseStat, C_defenseBase, C_luckStat, C_luckBase, C_origin, C_phrase, C_collection);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate sql: "+sql);
            db.execSQL(sql);

            sql = String.format("create table if not exists %s (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)", 
                    TABLE_cGroups, C_ID, C_cGroupName, C_cGroup1, C_cGroup2, C_cGroup3);
            //test script
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate sql: "+sql);
            //executes SQL statement
            db.execSQL(sql);

            sql = String.format("create table if not exists %s (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)", 
                    TABLE_collect, C_ID, C_skylanderid, C_collectid, C_collectName, C_collection);
            //test script
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate sql: "+sql);
            //executes SQL statement
            db.execSQL(sql);

        case 5:
            //only drops tblSkylander
            db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + TABLE_skylanders);
            Log.d(TAG, "onUpdate dropped table " + TABLE_skylanders);

            //only recreates tblSkylander
            sql = String.format("create table %s (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s INTEGER,  %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s TEXT, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)", 
                    TABLE_skylanders, C_ID, C_skyid, C_depth, C_preName, C_mainName, C_descName, C_element, C_figureType, C_pic, C_primePower, C_noOfFigures, C_game, C_attackStat, C_attackBase, C_agilityStat, C_agilityBase, C_defenseStat, C_defenseBase, C_luckStat, C_luckBase, C_origin, C_phrase, C_collection);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate sql: "+sql);
            db.execSQL(sql);

            sql = String.format("create table if not exists %s (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)", 
                    TABLE_cGroups, C_ID, C_cGroupName, C_cGroup1, C_cGroup2, C_cGroup3);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate sql: "+sql);
            db.execSQL(sql);

            sql = String.format("create table if not exists %s (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s INTEGER, %s INTEGER, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)", 
                    TABLE_collect, C_ID, C_skylanderid, C_collectid, C_collectName, C_collection);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate sql: "+sql);
            db.execSQL(sql);
    }   

}
```

}

Comment: Your `case` blocks are missing a `break` - is that intentional? I deleted my answer regarding that but it could be an explanation for the messed up upgrade logic.

Comment: Please take time to construct a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: laalto - I thought that by leaving out the break if someone was updating an older version it would start with whatever version they are on and work through all of the upgrades. Is that not the case?

Comment: Xan - I cut some code out but the rest that is posted is required for code to run properly and display my onCreate and onUpgrade processes.